# Validating "Relationship" fields with ExpressionEngine Channel Form (SafeCracker)

Tags: safecracker, validation

I'm trying to get the built in ExpressionEngine Channel Form (formerly Safecracker) validation working for a custom relationship field I have. This is using the [rules parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#rules-my-field-name).

Markup snippet of the channel form below

```
{custom_fields}
{if field_name == "exp_entry_related_to"}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{field_name}">Context</label>
    <select name="{field_name}[data][]" id="{field_name}" class="form-control">
    {options}
        <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
    {/options}
    </select>
    <p class="error"></p>
</div>
{/if}
{custom_fields}
```

There is a requirement ([as per the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#id75), and per my testing) for the field name to be **exp_entry_related_to[data][]** for this to populate the channel data, but of course I can't target that field name i.e.

```
{!-- Neither of these work as expected --}
rules:exp_entry_related_to[data][]="required|min_length[1]"
rules:exp_entry_related_to="required|min_length[1]"
```

Has anyone got any idea how to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't setting a field as *required* in its fieldtype settings also make it required when submitted via a channel form (negating the need to make it required via the `rules` parameter)?

Comment: @DerekHogue You would think so. That is correct of text/textarea/checkbox fields, but in this case, the native EE relationship field does not work like that for some unknown reason.